# Intended date of arrival error in Schengen visa application

Tags: visas, schengen

I have applied to the Netherlands for a Schengen visa. While I was writing the intended date of arrival in the Schengen area, I wrote 28/7 instead of 29/7.
Could this cause a problem or for my visa to be refused?

Comment: Why do you think this would be a problem?

Comment: @Neusser, it would mean that the numbers in the itinerary don't add up. That's a bad start, but if everything else looks fine the visa may be granted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is unlikely to be a significant problem or be the cause for a refusal. One day earlier is would be preferable than one day later. The additional information you provide, flight details and hotel reservations, would clarify your actual arrival on the 29th, in addition to mentioning it during a visa interview.